# What is causing my custom zsh script terminal command to hang?

Tags: arrays, logging, random, time, zsh

I've created a custom zsh script for taking notes about my day and keeping track of time so I can fill out time sheets easier. It works fine most of the time but every now and again just hangs. It logs to the txt file even when it hangs but it doesn't execute the "say" command.

I think it's a problem with how I'm selecting the random string but I don't know enough about zsh to fix it.

I'm using zsh and this is in my .zshrc file.

```
createLog() {
  LOGFILE=$HOME/Google\ Drive/autosdls.txt
  # chmod 755 $LOGFILE

  LASTLINE="$(tail -1 $LOGFILE)"
  LASTTIME="$(grep -oE "[[:digit:]]{10}" <<<"$LASTLINE")"
  TIME="$(date +%s)"
  TIMESPENT=$((($TIME-$LASTTIME)/60))
  echo "$TIMESPENT"
  echo "[ ] $TIMESPENT Minutes : $1 |$(date +%s)|" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1


  # Seed random generator
  RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)

  encouragements=("Greatjob!" "Thank you." "Productivity Node Assimilated" "Well done. Your ambition is matched only by your zeal" "Engage" "You're the best! Around! Nothing's gonna ever keep you down.")

  selectedexpression=${encouragements[($RANDOM % ${#encouragements[@]})-1]}
  say $selectedexpression
  # echo $selectedexpression
}
alias sdlog=createLog
```

Comment: zsh is not bash. I've edited and tagged accordingly.

Comment: First, what is `say`? Second, what is Google Drive? (Sounds like something that is actually over the network, so the hang could be a problem with network connectivity or something else out of your script's control.)

Comment: Say is a Mac command that audibly reads back to you whatever you pass it. Google Drive is a local drive that gets synced automatically to the cloud.

Comment: You don't give us a whole script and ask us to debug for you. If you suspect the random part is wrong, separate it out and test it.